# Cannot read text from pdf by ITextSharp in C#

Tags: c#, pdf, itext

I have two pdf files. On Sercurity tab both files have set Security Method: No Security and Document Assembly: Not Allowed and page Extraction: Not Allowed. Other items are allowed.
I using standart ITextSharp method to retrieve text from pdf:

```
PdfReader pdfReader = new PdfReader(fileName);

                for (int page = 1; page <= pdfReader.NumberOfPages; page++)
                {
                    ITextExtractionStrategy strategy = new SimpleTextExtractionStrategy(); //LocationTextExtractionStrategy();
                    string currentText = PdfTextExtractor.GetTextFromPage(pdfReader, page, strategy);

                    currentText = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(ASCIIEncoding.Convert(Encoding.Default, Encoding.UTF8, Encoding.Default.GetBytes(currentText)));
                    text.Append(currentText);
```

From first file i can get currentText wihtout any problem from second file I cannot retrieve text, currentText is empty. I was trying with LocationTextExtractionStrategy, but result is the same. I opened this file in SodaPDF and convert it to txt file but this file is empty too (while frist file is converted to txt without any problems).
It is possible to read text from this file from C# or with any other application? If I buy Adobe Reader I will convert this file to txt ?
What is difference between these two files ?

Thanks

Comment: If possible, please make those two files available so people can check them out

Comment: Can you copy/paste the text from Adobe Reader? If not, the text can't be extracted with any software, unless you OCR it.

Comment: Pdf file https://jumpshare.com/b/GRUHz0e1iXRPRpgL6nHE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I work as Social Media Developer at Aspose. I would suggest you to download and try [Aspose.Pdf for .NET](http://goo.gl/zOvbmd) to convert PDF to Text file. In case your file contains images and you need to extract the text from those images, you can use Aspose.Pdf to convert Pdf file to images and then perform OCR using [Aspose.OCR for .NET](http://www.aspose.com/.net/ocr-component.aspx).

Following is the sample code to convert PDf to Text using Aspose.Pdf for .NET

```
//open document
Document pdfDocument = new Document("input.pdf");
//create TextAbsorber object to extract text
TextAbsorber textAbsorber = new TextAbsorber();
//accept the absorber for all the pages
pdfDocument.Pages.Accept(textAbsorber);
//get the extracted text
string extractedText = textAbsorber.Text;
// create a writer and open the file
TextWriter tw = new StreamWriter("extracted-text.txt");
// write a line of text to the file
tw.WriteLine(extractedText);
// close the stream
tw.Close();
```

Please download a free trial and try it.

Comment: OCR has en error: Could not find file 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\Common7\IDE\2011.07.02 v1.0 Aspose.OCR.Resources.zip'.

Comment: You can download the resources file from the following link http://goo.gl/5ZKknp . Try it and in case you face any issue, let me know

Answer (score 1):

There may be a lot of pdf which actually are images. You cannot extracttext from imaged pdf as  Bruno Lowagie said. you need to go for third party OCR for this.

you ca use Adobe Acrobat to convert the pdf to editable format like word, html..

Comment: I think you are right, I think that within this pdf is image. I cannot copy text I can copy only image.
I try using OCR but result was very poor. I have downloaded free version of the OCR. Maybe any shareware version will be better.
If I buy Adobe Acrobat I convert to html without problems ?

Comment: Most of the times Acrobat will convert pdf images to html or word format. but I cannot guarantee you that. I've used acrobat for conversions like this and worked most of the times. I have actually converted your UlotkaCarefour.pdf to UlotkaCarefour.doc using acrobat and looks very good but not the converted html file. But the file size is 62 MB. Please contact me at robbienvz at hotmail dot com. I can send you the file there.

Comment: Thank you very much, I send email to you.